# Performance governor select low cpu frequency on battery

Tags: 16.04, power-management, performance, battery, cpu

When I am on battery the performance governor selects 800Mhz for my system speed even if the CPU is at 100% load. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 on a Lenovo P51.

I want that it increases CPU frequency more aggressively. How can I configure that?

```
$ cpufreq-info
cpufrequtils 008: cpufreq-info (C) Dominik Brodowski 2004-2009
Report errors and bugs to cpufreq@vger.kernel.org, please.
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 3.80 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance, powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 3.80 GHz.
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 800 MHz.
```